# Can't install Windows Phone 8.1 Emulator

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1, hyper-v

So I have a HP laptop, and as many HP users know it's a nightmare to install Hyper-V on it. But I somehow managed. Hyper-V is running on my laptop and I have all the necessary hardware requirements:

- SLAT is enabled
- VT-x is supported and enabled
- I'm running 64 bit Windows 8.1 Professional
- I'm running Visual Studio 2013 Professional Update 3
- Hardware D.E.P. is enabled and supported

And yet when I run the Phone Emulator installation I get the following display:
[image: Error I'm seeing]

I can't figure out what's going on or why I keep getting the error. Hyper-V is running as shown:

[image: Hyper-V is running]

I've spent two days already trying to figure this out and searching on Google for a solution to this problem. Some of the things I've tried:

- Flashing my BIOS
- Resolving issues with the Realtek BlueTooth driver (this causes issues with Hyper-V)
- Reseting my BIOS
- Doing a clean install of my whole system
- Installing all Windows Updates
- Installing all Visual Studio updates
- Enabled / Disabled D.E.P.

Any advice is appreciated. If you need the log from the emulator installation let me know and I'll post it here.

Thanks

**UPDATE**:

I've attempted to install winsows server standard 2012 and tried enababling hyper-v and installing visual studio and the phone emulator there, and that works and I'm able to run the emulators with no problem.

When I tried the same thing back after installing windows 8 again it installs hyper-v but fails to start windows after installing visual studio update 2 with the phone images etc. The only way I can boot back into windows is if I turn off virtualization in bios.

Comment: For what it's worth, that list of services is the same as mine. And I can run WP81 images.

Comment: that's nice and all but that doesn't solve the problem I'm having... but thanks for your input.

Comment: Please upload the log file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out that HP Pavilion laptops support all that is needed to run Hyper-V, however it looks as if HP is blocking the SLAT functionality from working properly with Hyper-V thus not allowing it to run correctly. This looks like it's blocked at the BIOS level.

Updating the BIOS doesn't solve the issue.

The way I came to this conclusion is that Windows Server running Hyper-V runs the Windows Phone emulator with no problems, and it's a Microsoft decision to not require SLAT when running Hyper-V on Windows Server while requiring it on Desktop version of Windows.

Seeing how I paid extra for a more powerful laptop to be able to use features like Hyper-V, and to have an experience such as this due to a manufacturer configuration has left a bitter taste in my mouth. Needless to say this is the LAST time I'll ever buy an HP laptop.